# Theano: Operate on nonzero elements of sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I'm trying to take the `exp` of nonzero elements in a sparse theano variable. I have the current code:

```
A = T.matrix("Some matrix with many zeros")
A_sparse = theano.sparse.csc_from_dense(A)
```

I'm trying to do something that's equivalent to the following numpy syntax:

```
mask = (A_sparse != 0)
A_sparse[mask] = np.exp(A_sparse[mask])
```

but Theano doesn't support `!=` masks yet. (And `(A_sparse > 0) | (A_sparse < 0)` doesn't seem to work either.)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for sparse matrices in Theano is incomplete, so some things are tricky to achieve. You can use `theano.sparse.structured_exp(A_sparse)` in that particular case, but I try to answer your question more generally below.

**Comparison**

In Theano one would normally use the comparison operators described here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html

For example, instead of `A != 0`, one would write `T.neq(A, 0)`. With sparse matrices one has to use the comparison operators in `theano.sparse`. Both operators have to be sparse matrices, and the result is also a sparse matrix:

```
mask = theano.sparse.neq(A_sparse, theano.sparse.sp_zeros_like(A_sparse))
```

**Modifying a Subtensor**

In order to modify part of a matrix, one can use `theano.tensor.set_subtensor`. With dense matrices this would work:

```
indices = mask.nonzero()
A = T.set_subtensor(A[indices], T.exp(A[indices]))
```

Notice that Theano doesn't have a separated boolean type—the mask is zeros and ones—so `nonzero()` has to be called first to take the indices of the nonzero elements. Furthermore, this is not implemented for sparse matrices.

**Operating on Nonzero Sparse Elements**

Theano provides sparse operations that are said to be structured and operate only on the nonzero elements. See:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/sparse.html#structured-operation

More precisely, they operate on the `data` attribute of a sparse matrix, independent of the indices of the elements. Such operations are straightforward to implement. Note that the structured operations will operate on all the values in the `data` array, also those that are explicitly set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing this with the `scipy.sparse` module.  I don't know how `theano` implements its sparse.  It's likely to be based on similar ideas (since it uses name like `csc`)

```
In [224]: A=sparse.csc_matrix([[1.,0,0,2,0],[0,0,3,0,0],[0,1,1,2,0]])

In [225]: A.A
Out[225]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  0.]])

In [226]: A.data
Out[226]: array([ 1.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  2.])

In [227]: A.data[:]=np.exp(A.data)

In [228]: A.A
Out[228]: 
array([[  2.71828183,   0.        ,   0.        ,   7.3890561 ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,  20.08553692,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   2.71828183,   2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,   0.        ]])
```

The main attributes of the `csc` format at `data`, `indices`, `indptr`.  It's possible that `data` has some 0 values if you fiddle with them after creation, but a freshly created matrix shouldn't.

The matrix also has a `nonzero` method modeled on the `numpy` one.  In practice it converts the matrix to `coo` format, filters out any zero values, and returns the `row` and `col` attributes:

```
In [229]: A.nonzero()
Out[229]: (array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]))
```

And the `csc` format allows indexing just as a dense numpy array:

```
In [230]: A[A.nonzero()]
Out[230]: 
matrix([[  2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,  20.08553692,   2.71828183,
           2.71828183,   7.3890561 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`T.where` works.

`A_sparse = T.where(A_sparse == 0, 0, T.exp(A_sparse))`

@Seppo Envari's answer seems faster though. So I'll accept his answer.